# Image() does not accept width and height

Tags: javascript, image

I ran into a very strange problem. I use the promises method to load images asynchronously and stuff.

```
loadImage(name, src, width, height) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const image = new Image();
        this._Assets[name] = image;
        image.onload = () => resolve(name);
        image.onerror = () => reject(`failed to load ${name}`);
        image.src = src;
        if (width != void 0) image.width = width;
        if (height != void 0) image.height = height;
    });
}
```

As you can see, I am assigning width and height parameters to the image, but it doesn't work. The image has width and height in properties, however the image itself is displayed through the context.drawimage using naturalwidth and naturalheight. However when I try to assign to the image already after the image is loaded. it gives me an error: cannot set property width, but the image itself is cropped. I've tried passing parameters right away to new Image (width, height), but it didn't get anywhere.
If we try to pass parameters  in drawimage

```
assets[`bg`].width
assets[`bg`].height
```

then everything works

Comment: Try `image.style.width = width + 'px';`

Comment: also worth checking any css styles

Comment: @Barmar  Using style, the parameters are set to the original height and width

Comment: @t3dodson I haven't connected any styles.

Comment: @Fraybyl I'm pretty sure something else is the issue. I don't know how you are attaching the `_Assets` array to the dom. I made a similar example to your code and it is working. https://jsfiddle.net/c4opfn8a/2/

Comment: @t3dodson 
Then I pass to the constructor an object with a name in which the object contains a link and width with height
https://jsfiddle.net/6pcvorzL/

Answer (score 0):

That's normal, [`CanvasRenderingContext2d.drawImage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) won't look at all at the `width` and `height` attributes of your HTMLImageElement, with only x and y params, it will use the intrinsic dimensions of the source image.

However this method comes with a few different signatures which allow you to set different dimensions:

```js
const image = new Image();
image.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png";
image.onload = e => {
  const ctx = document.querySelector( "canvas" ).getContext( "2d" );
  ctx.drawImage( image, 0, 0 ); // use intrinsic dimensions
  ctx.drawImage( image, 0, 0, 150, 150 ); // take the full source and resize to 150x150
  ctx.drawImage( image, 0, 0, 350, 350, 160, 0, 50, 50 ); // take the source rectangle at 0,0,350,350 and draw it in a 50x50 rectangle
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Note that if you plan to use this Image only for drawing on a canvas, there exists the [ImageBitmap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/createImageBitmap) interface, which allows you to set the dimensions at construction, **but this option is currently only available in Chrome browser**, though you could easily write a polyfill returning a resized canvas for other browsers.

```js
(async () => {
  const blob = await fetch( "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png" )
    .then( (resp) => resp.blob() );
  const image = await createImageBitmap( blob, { resizeWidth: 150, resizeHeight: 150 } );
  const ctx = document.querySelector( "canvas" ).getContext( "2d" );
  ctx.drawImage( image, 0, 0 ); // resized
})().catch( console.error );
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: I understand and know this, but I want the images to change their resolution to the one I need right after loading.

Comment: Well use the method as it is expected: pass your dimensions.